# Two spreadsheets into one - column with duplicate reference to a job but different info on rows - Needs to be on one row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

trying to create a worksheet from two other worksheets which contain a column with job numbers that are duplicated in different rows, the information is different on each row but I need them to be on the same row

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to separated by commas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for once, the Community Bot is right, in that the image you give seems like you were careful to make it hard to provide actual formulas. So the answer here will not do so. You'll have to take the concepts and write the formulas yourself.

Fortunately for you, or anyone finding the Question in the future, it's actually exceeding easy.

You have two sets of data that share at least one matching set of data which is unique, so that it is clear what data goes together, and in a single column in each data set, so it is easily addressable. (Having to use, say, three columns of data to make a single key is not hard, just "wordy" making formulas harder to read for understanding. So while theoretically just as easy, practical concerns make it seem harder.)

Presumably both existing data sets are "complete" - as in every job number existing in one exists in the other. You do not indicate differently, for instance, by saying what you'd like to get if data is missing in one set. But one can have those cells result in `""` which appears, and is treated in most ways, as a blank. Not much else to address about that.

If they ARE the same "size" (all the job numbers in either existing spreadsheet DO exist in the other, so if 1,000 job numbers are in one, the same 1,000 records are in the other, then the first step is to just pick one of them, maybe a coin toss, to be the source of job numbers in the new spreadsheet. If one has more job numbers than the other, then pick that one, the one with more records.

So, in the job number column of the new spreadsheet, in the cell you want them to start, place a formula like the following which simply specifies the range address in the chosen old spreadsheet:

```
=A2:A7234
```

You tagged the Question as not needing an answer for older Excel versions so I assume you have `Spill` functionality. So the one formula will `Spill` all that spreadsheet's job numbers down that column. Easiest is opening the two source spreadsheets, and a new one, then when making the formula, typing `=` and then mousing to the right spreadsheet and clicking on the start cell, and then the ending cell or typing its address. That way the proper crafting to read from that other file will happen for you instead of you having to know how to write it yourself.

Now that you have the job number list, you need the rest of the data from the two spreadsheets. You have options here. If you want a really simple collection, you can simply expand the above formula to use the rightmost column, as in maybe that's column K so your formula would be like this:

```
=A2:K7234
```

and all 11 columns (job numbers plus ten others) will `Spill` into place. Then you'd collect the data from the other spreadsheet by arrowing past them and in column L putting the formula to collect the other one's data.

That formula could be a simple `XLOOKUP`... if it weren't crippled (you can only get a single column out of it at a time). `VLOOKUP` would also work beautifully, if Excel allowed it to use two oddnesses in its formula. You could write something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,A1:D10,{2,3,4},false)
```

and it would return all three columns of data for that SINGLE lookup value. (The `{2,3,4}` rather than, say, `2` only is what I'm calling oddness #1.) But change that single lookup value to a vertical range and it will only return the first of those columns, not all three. (Using the range for the lookup value is what I'm calling the 2nd oddness.) One of them at a time, you get what you want, but together to get a 2-D result... NO.

However, `INDEX` will do very nicely. Actually, `INDEX/MATCH` but `INDEX` is doing the "good stuff" by itself with `MATCH` doing its usual, not "odd", thing. So, like this:

```
=INDEX(L1:W7234,MATCH(A1:A7234,'[Other Spreadsheet]Sheet1'!A1:A7234,0),  {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12})
```

which is "bog standard" except for that last little bit that I separated by a couple spaces from the rest:  `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}`.

That can actually be a function instead if there are enough columns to make typing it a good source of error:  `SEQUENCE(1,12)` would do.

Notice that I did not write the range for `INDEX` to include the job number column. I don't have to since I have a column of those already and don't need to bring them in. By leaving it out, the columns of data in its range that I need are number 1 to whatever, NOT 2 to whatever, so I needn't do anything obnoxious to write the array constant or to write the `SEQUENCE` function.

So anyway, this will collect the 2nd spreadsheet's non-job number columns of data.

All done.

There are LOADS of choices you might wish to make that could complicate this. Necessary if you need it done that way. For instance, you might want the columns from the two spreadsheets mixed rather than in two separate sets. You might want them "out of order" (so column 4 in the first one is column 18 in the new one and column 9 in it is column 3 in the new one). You might just want to use this to collect the data into one nicely matched up set, then immediately convert the formulas to simple text and delete the old spreadsheets. You might want to keep a live connection with you or others adding information into the existing ("old") spreadsheets and this one collects both together. And needs to grow as the old ones grow.

And maybe other complications. Some things you might even want to do work with it in a way that's not realllly best given your new possiblities but you don't realize yet isn't necessary given those new possibilities so you may need to do things in a way that allows you some easy changing of the new spreadsheet as you do realize the better ways and want to do them.

For instance, you might want to be able to move columns around with formulas in them. NOT a possibility with things brought in in blocks like shown above. So while you could probably keep `Spill` functionality in place down each column, you might need a separate formula for each column allowing that moving them about. (If converting to text immediately after collection, that's not an issue as the formulas are gone and there are no more "blocks" of data.)

While some of that can be changed later, some may be harder, later, than other things. So thought about it ahead of time is useful. You are free to think about it and then ask other specific Questions on the same basic job.

Final thought is that if the job numbers in both spreadsheets are identical, you can actually simply sort both into the same order and copy and paste into the new one. Done. There's even a trick you can use to restore to the order one of them had (not both, of course!) before sorting (new Question).

The devil is truly in the details.

By the way, to make images more useful, either do not have the headers at all, or have them fully show. Half shown bedevils folks into thinking they're important and as helpful souls, spending wasted time on trying to make them out. They're not important here, actually, nothing was, image-wise, as your text description was perfectly sufficient to see what you wanted (well... if what I described above here wasn't what you wanted, it was a bad description since it was so clearly this!), the image wasn't needed. However, again, helpful souls who realize they've wasted time trying to figure out poor details only to find they never mattered are then human people who may... feel rather less helpful for a time. If those headers were readable and they realized nothing in the image mattered in just a few seconds, that probably wouldn't happen. That's my (trying to be helpful)/(preachiness) - you choose which of them - for the day.